# Save/Open full PyQt5 project

Tags: python, pyqt5, pickle

How can I save my PyQt5 project with all variales, widgets. I also need to reload all the things of application which was input aqq11t previous.
I tried with pickle. may be pickle have some limitations.
If possible please help me.

Comment: PyQt5 project? What do you mean? Dump memory?

Comment: Pyqt5 windows application